# Why doesn't this distribution function integrate to $1$?

Tags: probability

I have this Weibull density function,

$$ f(x) = 0.25 \left| 1-x \right|^{-0.5}  \exp(-\left| 1-x \right|^{0.5})$$

Because of the absolute value, this is split into 2 cases.

Its cumulative function

$$F(a)=\int f(x) \; dx = \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{2} e^{-\left( 1-a \right)^{0.5}} -\frac{1}{2} e^{-1} & 0<a\le 1 \\  \\
   1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-{(a-1)^{0.5}}} - \frac{1}{2} e^{-1} & 1<a
\end{cases}$$

I take a=$\infty$, this cdf doesn't integrate to 1??

$$\left[1-\frac{1}{2} e^{-(a-1)^{0.5}} - \frac{1}{2} e^{-1}\right]_1^\infty = 1 - \frac{1}{2} e^{-1}$$
What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a cumulative distribution function, you must integrate from $-\infty$. 
That is, $$F(a)=\int_{-\infty}^a f(x)\,dx.$$
If you do that, you get the right answer
$$F(a)=\begin{cases} \exp(-\sqrt{1-a})/2 & \text{if } a\leq 1 \\[8pt]  
1-\exp(-\sqrt{a-1})/2 &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Hey Bryon, the interval for Weilbull is $x\ge 0$, correct?  This see this on Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution

Comment: @user1061210 Well, the function in your question is not a Weibull density, so I don't think the Wikipedia page is relevant to your question.

Comment: @Bryon, you know what, I'll take your word for it, even though it is clearly read Weibull Distribution on the page.  It reason being is, it integrates to one! yes!

Comment: Here it is $$F(a)=\int{f(x)dx}=\left\{ \begin{array}{*{35}{l}}
   \frac{1}{2}{{e}^{-{{\left( 1-a \right)}^{0.5}}}} & a\le 1  \\
   \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}{{e}^{-{{(a-1)}^{0.5}}}} & 1<a  \\
\end{array} \right.$$

How do I find the inverse of it?  I am taking it piece by piece.  But there is a negative sign in the exponent.

Comment: actually, I got it!  Thank everyone for trying to help.